# How to exclude folders from backup

Tags: windows-7, backup

I use the main HDD to make daily incremental backups of the OS partition and an old HDD to backup the main HDD (I plug it only when backing up), but I don't need to backup the 'backup files' again, so I googled it and found these registry keys

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToSnapshot

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToBackup

Adding folders in 'FilesNotToBackup' didn't work with the first partition (270 GiB of data, took 2 hours to backup) so I made some tests on a small RAM Disk (150MB) and the only thing that worked is to add the folder's FULL PATH in 'FilesNotToSnapshot'

So my question is whether this is correct or am I missing something, because I want to backup the remaining partition which is 320+ GiB of data and will take a long time if it didn't exclude unwanted folders.

Comment: If you're doing image backups, then you are making snapshots and you need to use "FilesNotToSnapShot".  You say it works for you in your tests, so what's the question to us exactly?

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing an image backup, didn't know that it's called snapshot.
 The question was whether or not it will work on a 'Real' Partition, since the one I used for tests was a 'RAM Drive' and it's formatted using FAT file system not NTFS, I didn't know if that could make any difference.

Comment: After making the backup, I found that some files in some folders that I have excluded from backup, were backed up anyway.
So I managed to empty a partition and added some folders in it, excluded some of them and did the backup many times and in every try the same files are backed up anyway. I chose a video file and changed its name, extension, compressed/uncompressed it and every time it was backed up. The only thing that worked was to re-encode the video (kept the original name) and it was excluded from the backup as it should.
Any one knows how does this really work?